# Android Studio, LibGDX auto-increase speed after certain time has passed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I am making a project, I'm learning LibGDX but so far, the project has been going good, however, the tutorial does not show on how to increase speed after a certain amount of time has passed, ex( after 10 seconds had passed, I want my enemies to increase their speed at 0.1f, which means 10 percent and after another 10 seconds have passed, auto-increase the speed to 0.2f and so on.) This is the only part of the code I need to change to make their enemies increase their speed `public static final Vector2 ENEMY_LINEAR_VELOCITY = new Vector2(-10f, 0);` The tutorial is here ('http://williammora.com/a-running-game-with-libgdx-part-1/') How do I do this? Could someone please help me? I would greatly appreciate it!

Constants class:

```
package com.avoidcrashjump;

import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


/**
 * Created by Felipe on 2/29/2016.
 */
public class Constants {
    public static final int APP_WIDTH = 1024;
    public static final int APP_HEIGHT = 640;

    public static final Vector2 WORLD_GRAVITY = new Vector2(0, -10);

    public static final float GROUND_X = 0;
    public static final float GROUND_Y = 0;
    public static final float GROUND_WIDTH = 50f;
    public static final float GROUND_HEIGHT = 2f;
    public static final float GROUND_DENSITY = 0f;
    public static final float PLAYER_X = 2;
    public static final float PLAYER_Y = GROUND_Y + GROUND_HEIGHT;
    public static final float PLAYER_WIDTH = 1f;
    public static final float PLAYER_HEIGHT = 1f;
    public static final float PLAYER_GRAVITY_SCALE = 2.5f;
    public static float PLAYER_DENSITY = 0.5f;
    public static final float PLAYER_DODGE_X = 2f;
    public static final float PLAYER_DODGE_Y = 1.5f;
    public static final Vector2 PLAYER_JUMPING_LINEAR_IMPULSE = new Vector2(0,13f);
    public static final float PLAYER_HIT_ANGULAR_IMPULSE = 10f;
    public static final float ENEMY_X = 25f;
    public static final float ENEMY_DENSITY = PLAYER_DENSITY;
    public static final float RUNNING_SHORT_ENEMY_Y = 1.5f;
    public static final float RUNNING_LONG_ENEMY_Y = 2f;
    public static final float FLYING_ENEMY_Y = 3f;
    public static final Vector2 ENEMY_LINEAR_VELOCITY = new Vector2(-10f, 0);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is named `Constants` and your speed is declared using `final`. Name of the class inform us that we should not try to change those and `final` doesn't allow us to do that.

But if you change your variable declaration (move it somewhere and delete `final` keyword). To make it increase you can use `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()`.

Create a variable to count passed time:

```
float timer = 0;
```

then in your render() method

```
timer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //returns time between two frames
if(timer > 10) { //after 10 seconds
    speed = speed * 1.1F;
    timer = 0; //reset timer
}
```